# Custom Environment Multiple Inputs

Tags: macros

I'm trying to write a new environment for the AIAA package (mostly just for fun/learning). I want to take the authors section:

```
\author{
First A. Author\thanks{Job Title, Department, Address, and AIAA Member Grade.}
\ and Second B. Author\thanksibid{1}\\
{\normalsize\itshape
Business or Academic Affiliation, City, Province, Zipcode, Country}\\
\and
Third C. Author\thanks{Job Title, Department, Address, and AIAA Member Grade.}\\
{\normalsize\itshape
Business or Academic Affiliation, City, Province, Zipcode, Country}
}
```

and have a more compact command like this (below is pseudo-code):

```
\begin{myAuthorsCode}{[Author1, Author2]}{[JobTitle1, JobTitle2]}{[Department1, Department2]}{[Address1, Address2]}{[AIAAMemberGrade1, AIAAMemberGrade2]}\end{myAuthorsCode}
```

I don't think the [ ] can be used like this but I've put them there to indicate that I'm trying to pass a vector (think MATLAB) as an input argument. I.e.:

```
\begin{myAuthorsCode}{AuthorNames}{JobTitles}{Departments}{Addresses}{MemberGrades}
\end{myAuthorsCode}
```

such that *"Author1"* and *"Author2"* are a subset of *"AuthorNames"*

and

*"JobTitle1"* and *"JobTitle2"* are a subset of *"JobTitles"*

and so on; and the command will work through it and pair them all up:

*AuthorNames(i)* with *JobTitles(i), Departments(i), Addresses(i),* and *MemberGrades(i);*

*AuthorNames(i+1)* with *JobTitles(i+1), Departments(i+1), Addresses(i+1),* and *MemberGrades(i+1)*

for i = 1:length(AuthorNames), where 'i' is an indexing variable.

So is this possible? I'd like to do it without needing any external packages (i.e. basic latex) if possible. How extensive is Latex's ability to handle things like this? It's not MATLAB of course but how much logic can you put into latex?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sure, this is possible, but it would be easier to input and easier to write if the input was sorted by author: `\AuthorsCode{{Author1, JobTitle1, Dept1, Address1,Grade1},{Author2, JobTitle2, Dept2, Address2,Grade2},...}`. Do you really want the syntax proposed in the OP?

Comment: Hello fellow Andrew haha and the syntax isn't the biggest deal... You're right that sorting by author would be smarter actually. It's more of a "where to start" than "show me how to do it" post. Can I used nested { } brackets for that kind of input?

Comment: @als0052 So each author has five properties AuthorName, JobTitle, Department, Address, MemberGrade. What kind of notation do you wish for handling the case that with some of the authors some of the properties are not provided/do have an empty value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As LaTeX is itself a TeX package I don't really understand why you want to do this without using external packages. I guess that the short answer is that this is not possible using LaTeX alone as it does not provide the tools that you need but you can do this if, instead, you revert to using the underlying TeX engine.

I don't know the `AIAA package` and, in particular, what the `\author{...}` command expects. It is probably similar to the usual `\author{...}` command but as the MWE treats the three authors slightly differently the code below only shows how to break up a comma separated list of "author-stuff pairs".

The basic idea is to use the TeX primitive `\def` command to separate the "author" from the "stuff", which you can do with:

```
\def\BreakUpAuthor#1,#2!{Author: #1, Stuff: #2.}
```

So `#1` and `#2` are separated by a comma and `#2` finishes when we see an exclamation mark. We could use anything instead of `!`. I used `!`  because it is convenient and I think that it is unlikely to occur in "stuff". Next we need to "loop over" a comma separated list of author-stuff pairs, which we can do recursively using

```
\def\AuthorLoop#1,#2!{
    \BreakAuthor#1!\if\relax#2\relax\else\AuthorLoop#2!\fi
}
```

So this passes `#1!`, which is an author-stuff pair, to `\BreakAuthor` and if `#2` is not "empty" then it calls `\AuthorLoop` again with `#2!`.
Notice that this adds the exclamation mark that marks the end of `#2`. (In fact, this is not so robust and, as below, it is better to use `\detokenize` to sanitize `#2`.) To get this to work it is now enough to define

```
\newcommand\Author[1]{\AuthorLoop#1,!}
```

Notice that this sets the last author-stuff pair to be "empty" via the `,!` that appears after `#1` because there is nothing between the last comma and the exclamation mark. If we now use

```
\Author{{Author1, Stuff1},{Author2,Stuff2}}
```

what happens is that `\AuthorLoop` sees `#1=Author1, Stuff1` and `#2={Author2,Stuff2},`, so it gives `#1!` to `\BreakUpAuthor` and then calls itself with `#2!`. On the second run through, `#1=Author2,Stuff2` and `#2` is empty so the looping stops. Exclamation marks get added many times throughout this process but they, and the commas, are just used to demarcate the parameters to the macros so they are discarded at each step and never printed.

Putting this all together, the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt% nicer looking output
\let\And\newline% default separator
\def\BreakUpAuthor#1,#2!{% Author, stuff
 Author: #1, Stuff: #2.
}
\def\AuthorLoop#1,#2!{\separator\let\separator\And% use and set \separator=\and
   \BreakUpAuthor#1!% break up author and stuff
   \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax\else\AuthorLoop#2!\fi% loop if non-empty
}
\newcommand\Authors[1]{\let\separator\relax\AuthorLoop#1,!}% set separator and loop

\begin{document}

\Authors{{First Author, stuff},{Second author, more stuff},{Third author, thanks}}

\end{document}
```

produces the output

[image]

For good measure I have also added a separator `\separator` that does nothing for the first author-stuff pair after which it becomes `\and`, which is set to `\newline`.

You'll find that there are issues with this code in that it can do strange things if there are spaces between items. For example, the code breaks on

```
\Authors{{First Author, stuff}, {Second author, more stuff}}
```

because of the space before `{Second author, more stuff}`. All of these things are fixable but rather than reinventing the wheel it is probably better to use the tools provided by the [etoolbox](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) or, if you are really keen, to delve into the wonders of [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl3).

**Edit**

By way of contrast, here is one way to do this using a few packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}%   mainly for \SplitArgument
\usepackage{etoolbox}% for \forcsvlist

\parindent=0pt% nicer looking output
\let\And\newline% default separator

\NewDocumentCommand\AnAuthor{mm}{\separator\let\separator\And%
  Author: #1, Stuff: #2.}
\NewDocumentCommand\BreakUpAuthor{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{\AnAuthor #1}
\NewDocumentCommand\Authors{m}{%
  \let\separator\relax%  set the initial separator to nothing
  \forcsvlist\BreakUpAuthor{#1}% apply \BreakUpAuthor to each pair
}

\begin{document}

  \Authors{{First Author, stuff},{Second author, more stuff}, {Third author, thanks}}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same as before but this macro is far less sensitive to spaces in the input and, in particular, it accepts the input  that is problematic for the code above. The code is of similar length to before but, I think, it is more readable.

Comment: Ah ok... I skimmed that (supposed to be cramming for a final but meh). Anyways the AIAA package is just the package for AIAA papers and it has a few issues (as in won't compile right away lol). The author command is basically just the same as the regular author command I believe. I'll look back through this when exams are over. I was more or less just wondering how deep into input/output type of things with custom environments one can go in LaTeX

Answer (score 0):

**The [datatool-package of Dr. Nicola Talbot](https://ctan.org/pkg/datatool) might be of interest to you.**

---

**You wish to know how much logic you can put into LaTeX?**

Well—people say (La)TeX is Turing-complete.  `:-)`

---

**You wish to have things done without additional packages?**

Your wish is my command. `:-)`

The example below does without additional packages and without eTeX-extensions and the like.

The real challenge is implementing things in a way which does also work in full-expansion-contexts.

I. e., implementing your algorithms in a way where no temporary assignments will take place when the macros that form the implementation get carried out. `;-)`

I tried my very best with the example below.

The macro-mechanisms underlying the environment could even be used within `\csname..\endcsname` as long as the arguments passed by the users to these macro-mechanisms are suitable for `\csname..\endcsname` `;-)`

The problem with such apporaches at programming in (La)TeX is the likelihood of producing inscrutable code. `;->`

**I did deviate from your specifications in one aspect:**

You wish to maintain five lists:

- a list of author-names,
- a list of job-titles,
- a list of departments,
- a list of addresses,
- a list of member grades.

You wished these lists to be **comma-lists**, i.e., lists, where the single items are separated from each other by commas.

Instead I implemented things in a way where these lists are **lists of undelimited arguments**, i.e., lists where the singele items are nested within an opening curly brace and a closing curly brace.

I did so because comma-lists require comma-list-parsing, which implies

- treatment of spaces that probably surround the commas,
- special means for masking commas that are to be part of a single item,
- special means for masking spaces that should surround a single item,
- precautions for avoiding undesired brace-removal,
- and a lot more.

These things are feasible.

If you insist, I can do it.

But that will be a lot more code.

I think the level of inscrutability of what I produced by now is sufficient. `;-)`

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%%=============================================================================
%% Paraphernalia:
%%    \UD@firstoftwo, \UD@secondoftwo, \UD@PassFirstToSecond, \UD@Exchange
%%    \UD@CheckWhetherNull,
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\UD@firstoftwo[2]{#1}%
\newcommand\UD@secondoftwo[2]{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@PassFirstToSecond[2]{#2{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@Exchange[2]{#2#1}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%.............................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\UD@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \UD@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \UD@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\UD@firstoftwo{ }{}\UD@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Code for \ExtractKthArg
%%=============================================================================
%% Extract K-th inner undelimited argument:
%%
%% \UD@ExtractKthArg{<integer K>}{<list of undelimited args>} 
%% 
%% In case there is no K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does not deliver any token.
%% In case there is a K-th argument in <list of indelimited args> : 
%%   Does deliver that K-th argument with one level of surrounding braces removed
%%   if that was present and then in any case one level of braces added.
%%
%% Examples:
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{0}{ABCDE} yields: <nothing>
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{ABCDE} yields:  {C}
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{3}{AB{CD}E} yields:  {CD}
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{4}{{001}{002}{003}{004}{005}} yields: {004}
%%
%%   \ExtractKthArg{6}{{001}{002}{003}} yields: <nothing> 
%% 
%%   \ExtractKthArg{1}{{}{001}{002}{003}} yields: {}
%%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArg[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  % #1: <integer number K>
  \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck
  \expandafter{\romannumeral\number\number#1 000}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgCheck[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{ }{%
    \expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}{#2}%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}{ }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{%
      \UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop{#2\UD@SelDOm}%
    }{%
      \expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#2}%
      {\expandafter\UD@ExtractKthArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm{}%
\long\def\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1#2\UD@SelDOm{{#1}}%
\newcommand\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@firstoftwo{}#1}%
  { #1}%
  {\expandafter\UD@ExtractFirstArgLoop\expandafter{\UD@RemoveTillUD@SelDOm#1}}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Code for expandable incrementing of number without eTeX
%%=============================================================================
%% \UD@increment{<non-negative integeral number k as sequence of
%%                catcode-12-character-tokens
%%                from the set 0123456789>}
%% ->
%% <non-negative integeral  number (k+1) as sequence of
%%                catcode-12-character-tokens
%%                from the set 0123456789>
%%
%% Emptiness is interpreted as "0"
%%
%% Examples:
%%  \UD@increment{999} -> 1000
%%  \UD@increment{0} -> 1
%%  \UD@increment{} -> 1
%%
%% The result is delivered after two expansion-steps.
%%.........................................................................
\newcommand\UD@incrementrevert[3]{%
  \UD@incrementinnerrevert{#1}{#2}{}#3\relax
}%
\newcommand\UD@incrementinnerrevert[4]{%
  \ifx\relax#4%
    \expandafter\UD@firstoftwo
  \else
    \expandafter\UD@secondoftwo
  \fi
  {#1#3#2}{\UD@incrementinnerrevert{#1}{#2}{#4#3}}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@increment[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@incrementrevert{\UD@incrementfork{}}{\relax}{#1}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@incrementselect{}%
\long\def\UD@incrementselect#10123456789\relax#2#3!!{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@incrementfork[2]{%
  \UD@incrementselect
  #2123456789\relax{\UD@incrementinnerrevert{ }{}{}#11}%
  0#223456789\relax{\UD@incrementinnerrevert{ }{}{}#12}%
  01#23456789\relax{\UD@incrementinnerrevert{ }{}{}#13}%
  012#2456789\relax{\UD@incrementinnerrevert{ }{}{}#14}%
  0123#256789\relax{\UD@incrementinnerrevert{ }{}{}#15}%
  01234#26789\relax{\UD@incrementinnerrevert{ }{}{}#16}%
  012345#2789\relax{\UD@incrementinnerrevert{ }{}{}#17}%
  0123456#289\relax{\UD@incrementinnerrevert{ }{}{}#18}%
  01234567#29\relax{\UD@incrementinnerrevert{ }{}{}#19}%
  012345678#2\relax{\UD@incrementfork{#10}}%
  0123456789#2{\UD@incrementinnerrevert{ }{}{}#11\relax}%
  0123456789\relax{\UD@incrementinnerrevert{ }{}{}#11}%
 !!%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%%Code for turning name of data-field into number of undelimited macro-argument
%%   Possible data-field-names are:
%%    AuthorNames -> 1
%%    JobTitles -  > 2
%%    Departments -> 3
%%    Addresses   -> 4
%%    MemberGrades-> 5
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\@gobbletoexclam{}\long\def\@gobbletoexclam#1!{}
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam[1]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@gobbletoexclam#1!}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@DataFieldToNumber[1]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \UD@CheckWhetherNoExclam{#1}{%
    \UD@DataFieldFork!#1!JobTitles!Departments!Addresses!MemberGrades!{ 1}%
                     !AuthorNames!#1!Departments!Addresses!MemberGrades!{ 2}%
                     !AuthorNames!JobTitles!#1!Addresses!MemberGrades!{ 3}%
                     !AuthorNames!JobTitles!Departments!#1!MemberGrades!{ 4}%
                     !AuthorNames!JobTitles!Departments!Addresses!#1!{ 5}%
                     !AuthorNames!JobTitles!Departments!Addresses!MemberGrades!{ 0}%
    !!!!%
  }{ 0}%
}%
\newcommand\UD@DataFieldFork{}%
\long\def\UD@DataFieldFork
      #1!AuthorNames!JobTitles!Departments!Addresses!MemberGrades!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Code for returning data of datafield-index.
%%
%%   \ReturnDataFieldOfIndex{<datalist macro>}%
%%                          {<name of datafield>}%
%%                          {<index-number>}%
%%
%%   Example:
%%           \ReturnDataFieldOfIndex{\mymacro}{JobTitles}{3}
%%           returns the third JobTitle if existing.
%%
%%   Actually the phrase "JobTitles" gets transformed to the number 2, thus
%%   this returns the third argument that is nested within the second argument
%%   of the expansion of \mymacro.
%%   In case an argument is returned, it will always be nested in curly
%%   braces!
%%
%%   Returns nothing/emptiness/not even curly braces in case the 
%%   datafield does not exist.
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ReturnDataFieldOfIndex[2]{%
  \romannumeral0%
  \expandafter\InternalReturnDataFieldOfIndex
  \expandafter{#1}{\UD@DataFieldToNumber{#2}}%
}%
%%-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \romannumeral0\InternalReturnDataFieldOfIndex{<datalist>}%
%%                                              {<number of datafield>}%
%%                                              {<index-number>}%
%% (Here the <datalist-macro> is already expanded.)
\newcommand\InternalReturnDataFieldOfIndex[3]{%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \UD@ExtractKthArg{#2}{#1}%
  }{ }{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
    \UD@ExtractKthArg{#2}{#1}%
    {%
      \UD@firstoftwo{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}{} %
      \UD@ExtractKthArg{#3}%
    }%
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Code for returning data of all datafields with same index.
%%
%%   \ReturnAllDataFieldsOfIndex{<datalist macro>}{<index>}{<action to apply>}%
%%
%%   Extracts from each argument of the expansion of <datalist macro> the
%%   <index>-th argument nested inside that argument.
%%
%%   Prepends to the result the tokens that form <action to apply>
%%
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ReturnAllDataFieldsOfIndex[3]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\InternalReturnAllDataFieldsOfIndex
                \expandafter{\expandafter}%
                \expandafter{\expandafter1\expandafter}%
                \expandafter{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}%
\newcommand\InternalReturnAllDataFieldsOfIndex[5]{%
  % #1 - <DataFieldsCollectedSoFar>
  % #2 - <number of data-field>
  % #3 - <datalist>  
  % #4 - <index> 
  % #5 - <action to apply>
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \UD@ExtractKthArg{#2}{#3}%
  }{\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#1}{ }{ #5#1}}{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\UD@increment{#2}}%
      {%
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\InternalReturnAllDataFieldsOfIndex
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\UD@Exchange\expandafter{%
        \romannumeral0\InternalReturnDataFieldOfIndex{#3}{#2}{#4}}{#1}}%
      }%
      {#3}{#4}{#5}%
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Code for returning with each index data of all datafields with same index.
%%
%%   \ReturnAllDataFieldsOfEachIndex{<datalist macro>}%
%%                                  {<separator>}%
%%                                  {<action to apply>}%
%%
%%   With each possible <index>-value extracts from each argument of the
%%   expansion of <datalist macro> the <index>-th argument nested inside
%%   that argument. 
%%   With each possible <index>-value prepends <action to apply> and in case
%%   <index>-value > 1, also prepends <separator>.
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\ReturnAllDataFieldsOfEachIndex[3]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\InternalReturnAllDataFieldsOfEachIndex
                \expandafter{\expandafter}\expandafter{\expandafter1%
                \expandafter}\expandafter{#1}{#2}{#3}{}%
}%
\newcommand\InternalReturnAllDataFieldsOfEachIndex[6]{%
    % #1 - <data-rows collected so far>
    % #2 - <current index number>%
    % #3 - <data-list>
    % #4 - <separator>
    % #5 - <action to apply>
    % #6 - <separator in this iteration>
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull
  \expandafter{\romannumeral0\InternalReturnAllDataFieldsOfIndex{}{1}{#3}{#2}{}}{ #1}{%
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\UD@PassFirstToSecond
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\UD@increment{#2}}{%
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\InternalReturnAllDataFieldsOfEachIndex
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
        \expandafter\UD@Exchange
        \expandafter{\romannumeral0\InternalReturnAllDataFieldsOfIndex{}{1}{#3}{#2}{#5}}%
        {#1#6}%
      }%
    }%
    {#3}{#4}{#5}{#4}%
  }%
}%
%%=============================================================================
%% Code for building up the myAuthorsCode-environment:
%%=============================================================================
\newcommand\@authorlist{}%
\newenvironment{myAuthorsCode}[5]{%
  \renewcommand\@authorlist{{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}}%
  \global\let\@authorlist\@authorlist
  \author{%
    \ReturnAllDataFieldsOfEachIndex{\@authorlist}{\and}{\@PrintAuthor}%
  }%
}{}%
\newcommand\@PrintAuthor[5]{%
  #1\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2#3#4#5}{}{%
    \thanks{%
      #2%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#3}{}{\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2}{}{, }}#3%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#4}{}{\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2#3}{}{, }}#4%
      \UD@CheckWhetherNull{#5}{}{\UD@CheckWhetherNull{#2#3#4}{}{ and }}#5%
    }%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}

\title{My work}
\begin{myAuthorsCode}%
  %%    Datafield AuthorNames:
  {{Author A}{Author B}{Author C}{Author D}{Author E}}%
  %%    Datafield JobTitles:
  {{JobTitle A}{JobTitle B}{JobTitle C}{JobTitle D}{JobTitle E}}%
  %%    Datafield Departments:
  {{Department A}{Department B}{Department C}{Department D}{Department E}}%
  %%    Datafield Addresses:
  {{Address A}{Address B}{Address C}{Address D}{Address E}}%
  %%    Datafield MemberGrades:
  {{MemberGrade A}{MemberGrade B}{MemberGrade C}{MemberGrade D}{MemberGrade E}}%
\end{myAuthorsCode}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\maketitle\thispagestyle{empty}

\newpage

% Now testing the macros underlying the myAuthorsCode-environment:

\newcommand\PrintAllDataFieldsOfIndex[5]{%
  \textbf{Author-Name:} #1;\\
  \textbf{Job-Title:} #2;\\
  \textbf{Department:} #3;\\
  \textbf{Address:} #4;\\
  \textbf{Member Grade:} #5.%
}%
\newcommand\AuthorlistForTests{%
  %%    Datafield AuthorNames:
  {{author 1}{author 2}{author 3}{author 4}{author 5}}%
  %%    Datafield JobTitles:
  {{jobtitle 1}{jobtitle 2}{jobtitle 3}{jobtitle 4}{jobtitle 5}}%
  %%    Datafield Departments:
  {{department 1}{department 2}{department 3}{department 4}{department 5}}%
  %%    Datafield Addresses:
  {{address 1}{address 2}{address 3}{address 4}{address 5}}%
  %%    Datafield MemberGrades:
  {{membergrade 1}{membergrade 2}{membergrade 3}{membergrade 4}{membergrade 5}}%
}%

\begin{verbatim}
\newcommand\PrintAllDataFieldsOfIndex[5]{%
  \textbf{Author-Name:} #1;\\
  \textbf{Job-Title:} #2;\\
  \textbf{Department:} #3;\\
  \textbf{Address:} #4;\\
  \textbf{Member Grade:} #5.%
}%
\newcommand\AuthorlistForTests{%
  %%    Datafield AuthorNames:
  {{author 1}{author 2}{author 3}{author 4}{author 5}}%
  %%    Datafield JobTitles:
  {{jobtitle 1}{jobtitle 2}{jobtitle 3}{jobtitle 4}{jobtitle 5}}%
  %%    Datafield Departments:
  {{department 1}{department 2}{department 3}{department 4}{department 5}}%
  %%    Datafield Addresses:
  {{address 1}{address 2}{address 3}{address 4}{address 5}}%
  %%    Datafield MemberGrades:
  {{membergrade 1}{membergrade 2}{membergrade 3}{membergrade 4}{membergrade 5}}%
}%
\end{verbatim}

\hrulefill\vfill

\verb|\ReturnDataFieldOfIndex{\AuthorlistForTests}{Departments}{3}|%
\\\null\\\quad yields:\\\null\\%
\ReturnDataFieldOfIndex{\AuthorlistForTests}{Departments}{3}

\vfill

\verb|\ReturnDataFieldOfIndex{\AuthorlistForTests}{JobTitles}{2}|%
\\\null\\\quad yields:\\\null\\%
\ReturnDataFieldOfIndex{\AuthorlistForTests}{JobTitles}{2}%

\vfill

(Possible datafield-names are:\\
\verb|AuthorNames|, \verb|JobTitles|, \verb|Departments|, 
\verb|Addresses|, \verb|MemberGrades|.)

\vfill\hrulefill\vfill

\verb|\ReturnAllDataFieldsOfIndex{\AuthorlistForTests}{4}{\PrintAllDataFieldsOfIndex}|%
\\\null\\\quad yields:\\\null\\%
\ReturnAllDataFieldsOfIndex{\AuthorlistForTests}{4}{\PrintAllDataFieldsOfIndex}

\newpage

\verb|\ReturnAllDataFieldsOfEachIndex{\AuthorlistForTests}%|\\
\verb|                               {\\\null\dotfill\\}%|\\
\verb|                               {\PrintAllDataFieldsOfIndex}|%
\\\null\\\quad yields:\\\null\\%
\ReturnAllDataFieldsOfEachIndex{\AuthorlistForTests}%
                               {\\\null\dotfill\\}%
                               {\PrintAllDataFieldsOfIndex}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]